# Clean last search highlighting if either n or ? is not pressed?

Tags: vim, macvim

So I've been thinking...I really don't like that highlighting that vim does when you search for something... I either use it in 2 cases... to find a word, and/or to do an action up until that word. I rarely need the word highlighted unless I'm actually searching around for it, usually with n (next) or ? (previous). So I'm wondering if there is a way to make vim understand that after the search, if I don't use n or ?, remove the highlight, and if anything else is entered (like a motion) then just don't highlight it. I'm having problems explaining exactly what I want but hopefully you understand.

Comment: Why do you set highlighting if you don't like it? I find it rather useless so I leave it off (its default value) and I `:set incsearch` instead.

Comment: romainl: I don't mind it as long as I am actually searching... a lot of the times I can either be searching, or trying to delete / change to the word I'm trying to "search", hence not searching. Though if I can't find something that more closely mirrors what I want, I'll probably end up doing what you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following mapping to switch-off highlighting after I am done with a search:

```
map <silent> <leader>/ :noh<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with `nmap n n:set hlsearch<cr>`. Then I set `nnoremap <leader>n :set nohlsearch<cr>` to turn it off when I want. You could do the same for `N` with `nmap N N:set hlsearch<cr>`.